# Translation of "I hope you'll have a good time"

Tags: traduction

"I hope you'll have a good time in Marseille!"

> J'espère que tu vas ___ _______ à Marseille !

Should the verb be *avoir* or *passer*, and should the noun be *un bon temps*, *de bons temps*, *un bon moment*, or *de bons moments*?

What about

"I hope you'll have a good time listening to the music!"

Should the gerund part be translated with *en écoutant de la musique* or *à écouter de la musique*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In France the usual phrase for "have a good time" is *bien s'amuser.*

> J'espère que tu vas bien t'amuser.

Variations can be found according to context.
In your example I would say:

> *J'espère que tu passeras un moment agréable/ un bon moment/ un séjour agréable à Marseille*.
>
> *J'espère que tu passeras un moment agréable à écouter / en écoutant de la musique*.

If you're going to a party I'd rather tell you:

> *Amuse-toi bien!*

(Have a good time!)

Different expressions might be used in other French speaking countries. *Prendre du bon temps* sounds rather quaint in France but it might still be common in Quebec (to be confirmed).

Both gerund or *à + infinitive* can be used after *bien s'amuser* or *passer un bon moment*. But according to context the use of *à + infinitive* can be ambiguous with *un bon moment* that's why I would only use the gerund in that case.

*J'espère que tu passeras un bon moment à écouter de la musique*.

could either mean "I hope you spend a long time" or "I hope you have a good time".

Comment: Perso. je ne connais pas _prendre du bon temps_, mais je reconnais _passer du bon temps_. Avec un infinitif qui suivrait, on l'introduirait avec la prép. _à_; autrement il serait fréquent de voir un truc introduit par _en_, comme _en famille_. À l'oral.

Answer (score -1):

> Translation of “I hope you'll have a good time”

*J'espère que tu prendras du bon temps*

> I hope you have a good time listening to the music!

*J'espère que tu as pris du bon temps en écoutant de la musique*

Comment: The hope is for the future, not the past. I've changed "have" to "will have" to make it clearer.

Comment: `you have good time` means action is finished, `you'll have good time` action is in the future

Comment: @bklups "I hope you have a good time" is definitely a future action, it is not finished. A finished action can only be expressed in the past: "I hope you had a good time".